# Messed up bash prompt after printf

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash, bashrc

This annoying bug bothered me. When I type `printf foo` or `echo -n foo`, the bash prompt next becomes glitchy when I navigate through previous commands. Here is a snippet of my `.bashrc`

```
bash_get_exit_status(){ STATUS=$?; if [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]; then echo -en "\001\033[01;32m\002"; else echo -en "\001\033[01;31m\002"; fi; echo -n "[$STATUS]"; }
export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\$(bash_get_exit_status) \[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\\\$ "
```

Output of `bash --version`:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Behaviour of prompt:

```
echo -n foo #glitches prompt
echo -en "foo\nbar" #last line gets removed when scrolled up
echo -e "foo\nbar" #no problem
```

I cannot find any results online. I gave up and asked it here.

Comment: What do you mean by "glitchy"? What do you want to change?

Comment: please kindly read the post again. I made some edits

Comment: You still did not explain what "glitchy" means for you. I just see normal and expected behavior, consistent with not printing a new line at the end of the output.

Comment: Glitchy means unexpexcted stuff

Answer (score 0):

`bash_get_exit_status` creates/includes a number of non-printing characters and codes in your prompt. These makes bash confused.

BACKGROUND:
You must have a `\[` before, and `\]` after; thus enclosing the non-printing characters/codes/pieces.

More info:
`$ man bash` type a single `/` and then `PROMPTING` directly after it and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>